# Combining jquery's jedit with d3

Tags: d3.js, jeditable

I'm pretty new to d3 and trying to merge some jquery with d3 functionality.  Basically I want a list of paragraphs that I can let my users edit.

There's a nice jquery plugin for this called jedit which works perfectly for my needs : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

I can get this to work without a problem but when I try to use d3 to generate my paragraphs, I seem to be out of luck.

I have the following function for my jquery plugin:

```
$(function() {
        $(".editable_comments").editable("save.php", { }); 
});
```

which works fine on the following element:

```
<p class="editable_comments">test</p>
```

but not so much on the following d3 code:

```
<div id="comments" style="float:left; width:50px; padding-top:33px;">

</div>

<script  type="text/javascript" >

 d3.json("json_data.php?", function(data) {

 d3.select("#comments").selectAll("p")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d) {return d.NAME;})
    .attr("class", "editable_comments");

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Also, the context is not clear. I suspect that the call to ".editable" may be done before the d3 code, therefore the d3 generated elements are not made editable. Without the full context, we cannot tell.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context, I'll be more thorough next time.  You're right that the call to .editable was being done before the d3 code and this is why it wasn't working.  I moved the call into the end of the d3.json function and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling my .editable prior to the d3 code running which is why it wasn't "working" or more specifically why I couldn't edit the d3 generated paragraphs.

Once I moved the .editable call to the end of my d3.json function